# Object as parent of literals

Tags: java

I am building a Help system for my application.
The help system consist of a shell with a Toolbar Tree and a browser pane.
The Tree loads files in to nodes and when clicked the link opens a HTML file in the browser. When a button on the Toolbar is clicked text = browser.getText() is called and text being loaded through a buffer to a HTML tag stripper which being collected in three arrays and then parsed to the style creator for the styledtext editor.

- The buffer is integrated in the the tag reader class, i wanted to create a global class to use it when needed anywhere in the application but run into problems with constantinating char string etc when parsed to the buffer.class
- The array consists of three array which being filled with the tags found by the reader, i wanted the add method working globally to use it in the application where needed.
- I could use a List list = new ArrayList(); but for ease of use in overhead and better understanding i tried to use just array instead.

  ```
  public class XMLHtmlTagReader {
   private static  char startchar = '<';
   private static  char endchar= '>';
   private static  char[] closingchar ={'<','/'};
   private static  String startTag;
   private static  String endTag;
   private static  String tagValue;
   static String[] starttaglist = new String[]{"first","second","third","fourth"};
   static String[]tagvaluelist;// = new String[1];
   static String[] endtaglist;// = new String[1];
   int tagcount=0;
   static char newchar;
   static char newchar1;
   static int i=0;
   static int startcharint = -1;
   static int endcharint = -1; 
   static int closingcharint = -1;
   static int level=0;
   static int elm=0;
   boolean closing = false;
   static Object store[] = new Object[26];
   Object[][][] megastore = new Object[50][50][50];
   int storeCounter = 0;
   int count=-1;
   int Wmstore=0,WstoreCounter=0,Wv=0;
   int Rmstore=0;
   static int RstoreCounter=0;
   static int Rv=0;
   static int Rtmp;
   int Omstore=0;
   static int OstoreCounter=0;
   static int Ov=0;
   int mstore=0;
   long time =   3087;

  public static void main(String[] args) {
       XMLHtmlTagReader run=new XMLHtmlTagReader();
   }

   XMLHtmlTagReader(){
       long memstart = (Runtime.getRuntime().totalMemory()-       Runtime.getRuntime().freeMemory());
   System.out.println("Memory at start:"+memstart);
   long startTime = System.nanoTime();
   getStream("<html><title>hallo de titel ...</title><p>Dit is de text.</p><b>dikke text</b></html>");
   //for(int t=0;t<100000;t++){new com.pim.Buffer(endchar);}
   long estimatedTime = (System.nanoTime() - startTime);  
       //(System.currentTimeMillis() - startTime);
       //(System.nanoTime() - startTime)/1000000;
       //long calc = (estimatedTime/time)*100;
   System.out.println(memstart+"memstart  "+"execution time = "+estimatedTime+" is % sneller/langzamer  = "+(estimatedTime/time)*100+"Memory = "+(Runtime.getRuntime().totalMemory()-Runtime.getRuntime().freeMemory()));
  bufferWrite('E');
   }

  public static String getStream(String input) {

       while(input != null){
                          i++;
              try {
                  newchar = input.charAt(i);
                  }
              catch (java.lang.StringIndexOutOfBoundsException exception){
                  break;
                  }
              if(newchar!=closingchar[1]&&input.charAt(i-1)==startchar){
                  startcharint=i;
                          level++;
              }
              if(newchar==closingchar[1]&&input.charAt(i-1)==startchar) {
                  closingcharint=i;
                  tagValue = input.substring(endcharint+1,closingcharint-1);
                  if(tagValue!=null){log("valuetag ["+tagValue+"]->"+endcharint+" ->"+closingcharint);}
              }
               if(newchar==endchar)  {
                                          endcharint=i;
                                          if(startcharint>=0){
                                              startTag = input.substring(startcharint-1,endcharint+1);
                                                  log("starttag "+startTag);
                                          }
                                          else {startTag=" no Start tag found "; }
                                          if(closingcharint>0){
                                              endTag = input.substring(closingcharint-1,endcharint+1);
                                              level--;
                                                  log("endtag->"+endTag);
                                                  log("level->"+level);
                                          }
                                          else {  endTag=" no end tag found "; }
                                          closingcharint=0;
                                          startcharint=-1;
                                      }   
                  }
      startchar = 0;
      endchar = 0;
      closingchar = null;
      newchar = 0;
      newchar1 = 0;
      return input;
  }
  private static  void addElementToArray(String string){
      String[] tmpArray;
      int length = starttaglist.length;
      tmpArray = new String[length+1];
      System.arraycopy(starttaglist, 0,tmpArray , 0, length);
      tmpArray[length] = new String(string);
      starttaglist = null;
      starttaglist = new String[length+1];
      System.arraycopy(tmpArray, 0,starttaglist , 0, length+1);
      for(String tmp:starttaglist){
          System.out.println("Elements in Array  "+tmp);
          }
      tmpArray = null;
  }
  public static String[] getStartTag(){
      return starttaglist;
  }
  public static  String[] getTagValue(){
      for(String tmp:tagvaluelist){

      }
      return tagvaluelist;
  }
  public static  String[] getEndTag(){
      return endtaglist;
  }


  static Object bufferWrite(char value){
      store[OstoreCounter] =  new Object();
      store[OstoreCounter] = value;
      //System.out.println("bufferWrite=["+OstoreCounter+"] storeValue=["+store[OstoreCounter]+"] Ov="+Ov);
      if(Ov==30&&store[RstoreCounter] == null){
          Rtmp=Ov;
          Ov=0;
          }
      if(Ov==40){
          OstoreCounter++;
          Ov=0;
          }
          Ov++;
           char tmp  = (char)  bufferRead();
           return tmp;
  }

   static Object bufferRead(){
      Object tmp = store[RstoreCounter];
      //System.out.println("bufferRead=["+RstoreCounter+"] storeValue= ["+store[RstoreCounter]+"] Rv="+Rv);
      store[RstoreCounter] =  null;
      if(Rv==Rtmp){
          Rv=0;
          }
      if(Rv==40){
              RstoreCounter++;
              Rv=0;
              }
      //System.out.println("bufferRead reads till end of int"+Rtmp);
          Rv++;
          return tmp;
  }




   static void log(String txt){
              System.out.println(txt);
              }
  }
  ```

Comment: int is a primitive, Integer is the Object equivalent. Ie `Integer[] i = new Integer[10] {Integer.valueOf(0), Integer.valueOf(1), Integer.valueOf(2)};`

Comment: Your code has many syntax errors...  Object is not the parent class of int, it is Integer

Comment: Indeed it does :) Copy/paste/brain error! How about: `Integer[] i = {Integer.valueOf(0), Integer.valueOf(1), Integer.valueOf(2)};`

Comment: Its not copy paste, but thumbs on mobile. The code is for clarification of my question trying to understand the Why

Answer (score 0):

int is not an object

try it with

```
Integer i = new Integer[10];
```

This would work

Comment: Indeed. Was just about to answer :)

Comment: In the documents int is a child of Object as is string double etc Why dont the methode with object as a reference take the individual laterals as an object parsed to

Answer (score 0):

`int` is **not** a subclass of `Object`, `Integer` is.

Answer (score 0):

`Object` is not the superclass of a primitive like `int`, but of the type `Integer`. Another problem is your declaration. Use a length or initial values, not both:

```
Integer[] i = new Integer[] {0, 1, 2, null, null, null, null, null, null, null};
Integer[] i = new Integer[10];
```

To write a general method you need to use generics:

```
void <T> add(T object , T[] lateral);
```

The next problem is, an array has a fixed length, it cannot be extended. The index has always to be in the range [0..length-1], never length or length+1. To do so, you should use a `List`:

```
List<T> lateral = new ArrayList<Integer>();

void <T> add(T object , List<T> lateral) {
  literal.add(object);
}
```

The only chance to do such a thing with an array is to place the new value at the first non-null position:

```
void <T> add(T object , T[] lateral) {
  for (int i = 0; i < lateral.length; ++i) {
    if (lateral[i] == null) {
      lateral[i] = object;
      return;
    }
  }
  throw new IllegalStateException("array to short, no null value found to insert " + object);
}
```

PS: This is all Java 5 code, won't work with earlier versions!

Comment: Thx very educational, i wrote code to copy the array to tmp array with length +1. add the new value set oldarray = null then create a new array and copy tmp array to new array done. But i tried to use diffrent array types to add a value and changed the String[] to Object[] but it doesnt work and could not understand why. I will post the code tonight, because dont have my pc at work

Answer (score 0):

```
int is not a subclass of Object
```

But after **java 5** there is one concept called `auto Boxing` which convert your primitive data type to there respective wrapper class.So in this case.
 `add(6, i);`

`6` will be automatically converted into there wrapper class `Integer`. But the problem is with `i` , because your function  take Array of Object but `i` its array of integer. This can't be converted by JVM using AutoBoxing.

So if you try `add(6, string);` then it will not show any error.

Answer (score 0):

**-** First of all `int`, `char`, `boolean`, `byte`, `short`, etc are of primitive types.

**-** We have `Wrapper Object` of the above `primitives` and with the arrival of **Java 5** the feature called `Auto-Boxing` and `Un-Boxing` came into existence.

**Eg:**

```
int i = 5;

Integer intObj = new Integer(i);
```

**Now the method defination:**

`public <T extends Object> void doIt(ArrayList<T> arr){}`

**OR**

`public void doIt(ArrayList<? extends Object> arr){}`

Comment: Thx very educational, i wrote code to copy the array to tmp array with length +1. add the new value set oldarray = null then create a new array and copy tmp array to new array done. But i tried to use diffrent array types to add a value and changed the String[] to Object[] but it doesnt work and could not understand why. I will post the code tonight, because dont have my pc at work

Answer (score 0):

I could not getting it done parsing the array reference to the method

```
        private void addElementToArray(String string, String[] obj);
```

in stead i included the code in side the main method its not the cleanest way but it works well.

```
        tagValue = input.substring(endcharint+1,closingcharint-1);
        tmpArray = new String[tagvaluelist.length+1];
        System.arraycopy(tagvaluelist, 0,tmpArray , 0, tagvaluelist.length);
        tmpArray[tagvaluelist.length] = new String(tagValue);
        tagvaluelist = null;
        tagvaluelist = new String[tmpArray.length];
        System.arraycopy(tmpArray, 0, tagvaluelist , 0, tmpArray.length);
        tmpArray = null;
```

For the Buffer class to except primitive char i found a solution to parse the char as a object to the Buffer class and it works, hope its according the java rules though.

```
            newchar1 = input.charAt(i);
        Buffer buffer =  new Buffer(newchar1);
        buffer.buffer(newchar1);
            newchar = newchar1; // to test its going through the buffer
```

Buffer class:

```
     package com.test;


    public class Buffer {
         Object store[] = new Object[26];
         Object[][][] megastore = new Object[50][50][50];
         int Wmstore=0,WstoreCounter=0,Wv=0;
         int Rmstore=0,RstoreCounter=0,Rv=0,Rtmp;
         int Omstore=0,OstoreCounter=0,Ov=0;
         int mstore=0;
     public Object buffer(Object obj){
        return new Buffer(obj);}
 public Buffer(Object obj){
                bufferWrite(obj);
                store = null;
                megastore = null;
    }
Object bufferWrite(Object obj){
        store[OstoreCounter] =  new Object();
        store[OstoreCounter] = obj;
        System.out.println("bufferWrite=["+OstoreCounter+"] storeValue=["+store[OstoreCounter]+"]");// Ov="+Ov);
        if(Ov==30&&store[RstoreCounter] == null){
            Rtmp=Ov;
            Ov=0;
            }
        if(Ov==40){
            OstoreCounter++;
            Ov=0;
            }
            Ov++;
             Object tmp  =   bufferRead();
             return tmp;
    }

     Object bufferRead(){
        Object tmp = store[RstoreCounter];
        System.out.println("bufferRead=["+RstoreCounter+"] storeValue=["+store[RstoreCounter]+"]");// Rv="+Rv);
        store[RstoreCounter] =  null;
        if(Rv==Rtmp){
            Rv=0;
            }
        if(Rv==40){
                RstoreCounter++;
                Rv=0;
                }
        //System.out.println("bufferRead reads till end of int"+Rtmp);
            Rv++;
            return tmp;
    }
     void log(String txt){
                System.out.println(txt);
                }
      }
```